# Write to JSON file

Tags: php, json

does anyone know why it does not work?

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $twitchArray = array(
        "TwitchName" => $_POST['twitchName'],
        "TwitchHref" => $_POST['twitchHref'],
        "TwitchDescription" => $_POST['twitchDescription']
    );

    $json = json_encode($twitchArray);

    $file = 'twitch.json';

    file_put_contents($file, $json);

    echo json_decode('twitch.json');
}
?>
```

I really do not know why it does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: The argument to `json_decode()` must be JSON, not a filename. `var_dump(json_decode($json));`

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more detail about what input values you are testing with, what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead.  It is difficult to tell you why it won't work if you don't explain more about what you expect to happen vs what is happening.  Is an exception being thrown?  Is it not echoing what you expect it to?  Barman seems to have found at least one mistake, perhaps you can post back after making that change.  It appears as though you are encoding an array as JSON, saving it to a file, but what you do with it next is unclear.

Comment: What's the point of decoding a JSON you just created? The decoding should produce a data structure (array or object) similar to `$twitchArray`.

Comment: php code it alerdy write data to JSON but overwrites those existing

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decode a string `twitch.json`, not the variable file you've written contents to. You need to use `file_get_contents` to read the file, as you needed to use `file_put_contents` to write into the file.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $twitchArray = array(
        "TwitchName" => $_POST['twitchName'],
        "TwitchHref" => $_POST['twitchHref'],
        "TwitchDescription" => $_POST['twitchDescription']
    );

    $json = json_encode($twitchArray);

    $file = 'twitch.json';

    file_put_contents($file, $json);

    echo file_get_contents($file);
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

in order to echo the output json, all you need to do is

```
echo $json;
```

in your case assuming this is an altered version of your actual code, you need to pass a json string to `json_decode`, not a filename. See [json_decode on php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('twitch.json'));
```

however the above will result in echoing `Array` or `stdClass` or `null`, as the `twitch.json` file's contents will be converted to an array or object(or null if the json is not valid). So the correct way to echo the json content of a file should be

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```